# docker swarm placement spread

Tags: docker, server, docker-swarm

Say there is a 4-core server and a 8-core server and plan to start a service with 12 replicas, how to spread 4 app replicas to the 4-core server and 8 app replicas to the 8-core server using docker swarm?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a very nice solution but I would deploy a stack with 2 identical services - one with 4 replicas with placement constraint to place it on 4-core node and the other one with 8 replicas on the 8-core node.